# How can I see the effect of Angel Hair Braid?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-crusader

Recently I started playing Season 5, and I found an [Angel Hair Braid](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/angel-hair-braid).

It has an interesting legendary power.

> Punish gains the effect of every rune.

How can I tell that this effect is being applied? Does it matter which rune I select in Punish?

Is the only way to tell by watching your character?

Comment: The only visual effect is the animation changing when using the spell. Which rune you pick in the skills screen can be used to change the damage type, the other effects will always be active

Comment: How about the buff you get when hitting something with punish? Does it list all the effects?

Comment: Punish doesn't show a buff on the "buff bar" unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by @blgt it seems that setting the rune just adjusts the base damage type of the attack.

I've done some investigation and it turns out that the bonus is working, but the only way to see it is to attack whilst having your details panel open, so you can watch the stat changes.

I've uploaded a video to demonstrate the effect.